# Page title of VF page in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience

I have overridden the Standard New button with the VF page. I am getting the page title of VF page in classic view, but coming to Lightning experience, it is showing the "New X (where X refers to Object Label)". I want the VF page title in Lightning experience. Please let me know the possible ways to achieve this.

Thanks
Sannith

Answer (score 0):

> This is not possible in standard way, as Visualforce pages are embedded in an HTML iframe that’s displayed inside the Lightning Experience.

As a workaround you can create a lightning component with an iFrame pointing to the Visualforce page. Change the Page title in the init method of the lightning component.

Lightning Component Markup

```
    <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" >
        <aura:handler value="{!this}" name="init" action="{!c.init}"/>
        <iframe src="https://my-demo--c.eu11.visual.force.com/apex/MyVisualforcePage" frameBorder="0"/>
    </aura:component>
```

JS Controller

```
init: function(component, event, helper) {
   document.title = "Your Title";
}
```

You can follow this answer to make the VF Page URL dynamic.
[How to dynamically get VF page and Lightning page host name to use with Window.postMessage between VF and Lightning Component communication](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245530/how-to-dynamically-get-vf-page-and-lightning-page-host-name-to-use-with-window-p)